# how to use header renderer in AdvandedDataGrids in flex?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to filter my columns using Advanced Datagrids. It works weel for all the columns except for columns with header renderers. Any clue?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  headerText=" " editable="false" width="20" 
                                    sortable="false" textAlign="center" dataField="selected" 
                                    editorDataField="selected" id="selectednamesData" >
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CheckBox selected="{data.selected}" 
                                         click="applyfilters(event);">   
                                <mx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        import mx.controls.ComboBox;
                                        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;


                                        public function applyfilters(event:Event):void {
                                      //getting required data

                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </mx:Script>                
                            </mx:CheckBox>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer> 
   </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>       
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="Name_code" width="50"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="FirstName" dataField="FirstName_code" width="50"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="LastName" dataField="lastName_code" width="50"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="PhNum" dataField="Pnum_code" width="50"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Salary" dataField="salary_price"  width="75"
                    labelFunction="salaryPrice"  
                     headerRenderer="com.abc.myHeaderRenderer1"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="OriginCountry" dataField="Origin_Country"  width="75"                                                                                     
                        labelFunction="originFn"          
                      headerRenderer="com.dpp.myHeaderRenderer2"/>/>
```

I've defined my custom headerRenderers which were extended by label and text respectively.
I can compile my code without errors but Filters are not getting applied to the columns where i have headerRenderers. however filters are applied to remaining columns  Am i missing any anything??

Comment: there is an extra `/>` at the end of the code, is it?

Comment: Sorry. That's a typo error!!

Comment: Basically, How can i use a Custom HeaderRenderer which extends TEXT /LABEL in AdvancedDataGrid??